# Make ruby interpolation hello name of a friends

Tags: ruby

For this code:

```
def bonjour(*noms)
  noms.each{|i| puts 'bonjour #{i}'}
end

bonjour('Marc','pierre')
```

I get this output:

```
bonjour #{i}
bonjour #{i}
```

I don't understand why my interpolation does not work. Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` to use string interpolation:

```
def bonjour(*noms)
  noms.each { |i| puts "bonjour #{i}" }
end
```